# SwiftUI: Changing values in a Class

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

This is a menubar macOS app. I'm trying to change the dropdown window size with a button from the content view. This is my attempt so far.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var app = AppDelegate()

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            Text("Hello World")
                .padding(.top, 10)
            Button {
               biggerwindow()
            } label: {
                Image("tv")
             }
    }
}
    
    func biggerwindow(){
        app.popover.contentSize = NSSize(width: 800, height: 800 )
    }
}
```

Nothing happens when clicking on the button.

This is the AppDelegate class that contains the default values

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, ObservableObject {
    var popover = NSPopover.init()
    var statusBar: StatusBarController?

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the contents
        let contentView = ContentView()
        
        
        // Set the SwiftUI's ContentView to the Popover's ContentViewController
        popover.contentViewController = MainViewController()
      
        //default size of the menu bar window
        popover.contentSize = NSSize(width: 360, height: 360 )

        popover.contentViewController?.view = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
        // Create the Status Bar Item with the Popover
        statusBar = StatusBarController.init(popover)
      
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
```

Comment: Try to create a shared instance ```static let shared = NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate``` in appdelegate and then use ```AppDelegate.shared.popover.contentSize``` instead ```app.popover.contentSize```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

> ```
>     @ObservedObject var app = AppDelegate()
> ```

You're creating a new instance of `AppDelegate` here, with its own instance of `popover`. You need to use the existing instance of `AppDelegate` that was created at app launch. You can access the existing instance through the global `NSApplication.shared` object.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var app: AppDelegate { NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate }
```

Comment: Might I just recommend that you move `NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate` to a shared place. It's a commonly recurring pattern.

Comment: In this case, I would just pass `popover` to `ContentView` in its initializer.

Comment: Indeed, and SwiftUI actually makes this possible/pleasant (as opposed two the two-stage initialization pattern of AppKit when using interface builder)